# Is there a way to actively listen on bluetooth audio channel?

Tags: android, bluetooth, listener, headset

I want to be able to use the bluetooth headset as a microphone.

Is it possible to set it to microphone mode?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to use [startBluetoothSco()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#startBluetoothSco%28%29)

> This method can be used by applications wanting to send and received audio to/from a bluetooth SCO headset while the phone is not in call.

Answer (score 1):

```
AudioManager localAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService("audio");
            localAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
            localAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
            localAudioManager.setMode(2);
```